# ios7 with zxing, probably c++ compiler error

Tags: iphone, ios7, zxing

I get through zxing readme, and I searched for similar problems, because I know that was common error. But I still have problem with that. Im getting errors like:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "std::string::compare(std::string const&) const", referenced from:...

I have c++ language dialect and c++ standard library changed to compiler default. But i have Compiler for c/c++/o-c set to Apple LLVM 5.0.

If I need to provide any screenshots or something, just tell me.

Comment: Is the reference from your code or from something in a library?  If it's a library, did you build it or was it supplied as a binary?  Which Xcode version are you using?

Comment: It's supplied as a binary, xcode 5. Reference from library.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if your library was built with libstdc++ as the C++ standard library.  Try changing to that setting in your project instead of libc++, clean and rebuild.

Alternatively (and a better choice for the future of your project), see if there's a version of the library built with libc++.

Comment: where can I change it? Because I looked in build settings and there is no option to change that.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 5.0.2 and, in the build settings under Apple LLVM 5.0 - Language - C++, the C++ Standard Library setting shows me 3 options: libstdc++, libc++, and compiler default.

Answer (score 0):

With the release of iOS 7, Apple included the ability to detect barcodes through its [AV Foundation framework](https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/). The supported types are:

UPC-A, UPC-E, Code 39, Aztec, PDF417, QRCode and maybe 3 or 4 more.... so there is no need to use ZXing anymore.

Comment: Thats actually good to know :D Long time I didn't make something on iOS but maybe its time :p